Can shapefile hold style information?
I have been using Google Earth KML files for a while and I know they can contain style information such as line width and color. I've recently started working with shapefiles and learned that KML can be converted to a shapefile and the other way around.
Can a shapefile hold the style information as well so that if I send it to someone they will see it with the same style I chose?

No, shapefile does not hold style information.
In the layout manager, you can export a style to XML. You can share this file along with your shapefile with any person you like. For details see the QGIS documentation.
Depending on the importance of the file type you can also use the tool "Package layers", which allows you to save a file as geopackage with your individual styling.
